# OleDbConnection to MS Access: SQL query like clause with escape characters and wildcards

Tags: c#, ms-access, sql-like, oledbconnection

There must be some very obvious answer but i just can not see it nor find solution from web.

I try to count from db table how many rows contains file path LIKE "path".

In Access Settings-table I have rows where path field (short text type) containing string:

```
\\server\dir\something\
```

I want to count the rows where field begins with "\server\dir..".

After failing this with MS Access I started testing with mariaDB & heidiSQL and had some trial and error before getting valid answer with this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Settings` WHERE `path` LIKE "%\\\\\\\\server\\\\dir\\\\%"
-> returns Count(*) = 3
```

In C# i get same return with this (found again with trial and error):

```
string query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Settings WHERE path LIKE '%\\\\\\\\server\\\\dir\\\\%'";
var Test = MySqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(connString, query);
-> returns Count(*) = 3
```

Now I cant get the same work with C# and Access using OleDb library:

```
string query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Settings WHERE path LIKE '*\\\\\\\\server\\\\dir\\\\*'";
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(databsefile);
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
connection.Open();
var Test = command.ExecuteScalar();
-> returns Count(*) = 0
```

I have also tried queries (with C# and Access using OleDb library):

```
string query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Settings WHERE path LIKE '*\\\\server\\dir\\*'";
-> return count(*) = 0
string query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Settings WHERE path LIKE '*\\server\dir\*'";
-> return count(*) = 0
```

This works in MS Access 2013 giving valid result:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Settings WHERE path LIKE '*\\server\dir\*'
->returns Count(*) = 3
```

EDIT: Changed db table name table -> Settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Ms Access use * as a wildcard like [T_D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30804557/oledbconnection-to-ms-access-sql-query-like-clause-with-escape-characters-and-w#comment49657745_30804629) indicated and which is what my valide query use in MS Access. BUT like HansUp indicated C# OleDb API still uses ANSI wild cards.

But small correction even to that answer would be to escape the query in c#. So query returning valid answer is:

```
string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Settings WHERE path LIKE '%\\\\server\\dir\\%'";
OR
string query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Settings WHERE path LIKE '%\\server\dir\%'";
-> returns Count(*) = 3
```

HansUp also pointed that using ALIKE instead of LIKE % also works in MS Access so that way query is compatible with ANSI wildcard %

So here is my working solution (with command parameters):

```
string destFolder = @"\\server\\dir\";
string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Settings WHERE path LIKE @destFolder;";

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(mdbfile))
{
    using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@destFolder", "%" + destFolder + "%");
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            if ((int)command.ExecuteScalar() == 3)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            //handle OleDb error
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you use the @ before the string, you do not need to escape the backslashes again. And the placeholder for LIKEs is %, not *.

So try:

```
string query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE path LIKE '%\\\\server\\dir\\%'";
```

To avoid all that escaping though, consider using SQL parameters.

PS: table is a reserved keyword. You should not name a table table, this will always cause issues.

Comment: In MS Access the wildcard is * instead of % as can be seen here: https://developtheweb.wordpress.com/2008/03/17/the-sql-ms-access-like-statement/  Furthermore, the escaping is not needed for the C# application but probably for the specific db that interprets the *LIKE* condition string differently

Comment: That's why there are still 4 backslashes in my statement and not 8 like tried in the OP. ABout the wildcard: Sorry, my fault.

Comment: Sorry for taking while before getting back to this question.
I know the purpose of @ in front and that why I'm suprised that VALID result from c# & MariaDB (with mysql .net connector) comes with @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Settings WHERE path LIKE '%\\\\\\\\server\\\\dir\\\\%'"
I Also edited table name in original question (which was not the actual table name but the given name in example).
Maybe the answer could be one which was here but removed cause I didn't have time to come back during weekend. It stated that even Access wildcard is * OleDb needs %. I'll try that and come back.

Answer (score 1):

You reported this query works correctly in Access:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE path LIKE '*\server\dir*'
```

With your c# code, you are using OleDB to interface with the Access database.  And OleDb requires ANSI wildcards: `%` and `_` instead of `*` and `?`.

So, since the above query worked inside Access, this one should work from c#:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table] WHERE path LIKE '%\server\dir%'
```

Queries run with OleDb also seem to be more vulnerable to trouble with reserved words.  So I enclosed *table* in square brackets to avoid trouble.

If you want a query which will always work the same inside or outside of Access, use `ALike` instead of `Like`.  `ALike` signals the database engine to expect ANSI wild cards:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table] WHERE path ALIKE '%\server\dir%'
```

Comment: Very useful info. Find working c# code in the end of my own answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30839287/2628285